# Apexcharts: mixed chart candlestick + area chart (fill area between 2 data points )

Tags: javascript, apexcharts, candlesticks

I use ApexCharts js for make mixed chart. Candlesticks + on this candlestick I need placed area chart from start date to end date (range, for example between 1.4 to 1.5 ).

For candlestick series i use

```js
{
    x: new Date(timestamp),
    y: [open, high, low, close]  
},
```

- everything fine here.
  For area chart i faced with issue thats i cant make filled area between 2 points. For example candlesticks for data frame between 1.4 and 1.7 , and i need add area chart between 1.5 to 1.66, for example. But it always add area chart from lowest candlestick point to my highest value (from 1.4 as lower point to 1.66)

  [image]

For area chart series i add series as

```js
{
           x: new Date(tsmp),
           y: [1.4, 1.66]         
}
```

So have way to make area chart from 1.4 to 1.66 or it always build from lowest point at series ?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for my question. Mark ranges in options > anotations

```
  annotations: {
    position: "back",
    yaxis: [
      {
        label: {
          text: " "
        },
        y: 1.4,
        y2: 1.66,
        fillColor: "#00E396"
      },
      {
        label: {
          text: " "
        },
        y: 1.66,
        y2: 1.69,
        fillColor: "yellow"
      }
    ]
  }
```